# In Internet Explorer If element does not have tabIndex, it will return 0 as default value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, tabindex

I am getting tabIndex property using javascript, for this element

```
<div role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="-1">
 <div id="if_empty" tabindex="-1" type="radio" value="Show only if empty"></div>
 <label id="radioId" for="if_empty">Show only if empty</label>
</div>
```

It works perfectly in all browsers, except Internet Explorer.

```
const element = document.getElementById("radioId");
const tabIndex = element.tabIndex;

// tabIndex is -1 for Firefox/Chrome
// and it is equal 0 for Internet Explorer
```

How do I get the correct tabIndex in Internet Explorer?

Comment: According to MDN, if unspecified, the default value is 0. That means when one tab's, it jump based on markup location.

Comment: does `element.getAttribute("tabindex");` give you the correct result? Instead of `-1` it will give you `null` on other browsers

Comment: @LGSon but this does not make sense right? that means its tabbabble but it is not..

Comment: Are you asking _why_ an element is not tab-able or _why_ it has a given value? If the former, show us a [mcve], if latter, MDN has the answer.

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks,it looks like it might work, should I use `tabIndex` or `tabindex` ?

Comment: When I created a test case — https://jsbin.com/hajegizodi/1/edit?html,css,js,output — and tried it in Internet Explorer I was expecting (based on your question) to find that the label element was focusable, in the tab order, and thus should have `tabIndex` equal to `0` what I found was that it wasn't focusable, was not in the tab index, and had a `tabIndex` equal to `-1`. I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: `tabindex='-1'` should skip the element. See here https://jsfiddle.net/zg7j8owb/

Comment: @Quentin Okay so getting tabIndex with `getAttribute('tabIndex')` worked for me.

Comment: @LGSon According to the standard, there are two possible default values: "_Its default value is 0 for elements that are focusable and −1 for elements that are not focusable_" See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-tabindex

Comment: @Teemu Thanks...am aware, though OP asked about a radio, hence my first comment, but I see it actually was a label.

Comment: @LGSon Actually ... it was a bit confusing what is the target, the script is retrieving an input element, but the original question text says OP wants to retrieve a label element (OP edited the question 10 minutes after your comment).

Comment: @Teemu Okay, thanks...explains it, never checked that when read your comment :)

Comment: And this is actually an IE bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4365703/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was getting tabIndex with `getAttribute('tabIndex')`

```
    for (let i = 0; i < rootNode.childNodes.length; i++) {
      const child = rootNode.childNodes[i];

      if (child.nodeType === 1 && child.getAttribute('tabIndex') === 0) {
             //find tabbable element
      }

    }
```

Let me know if you don't like the question I will just remove it..

Comment: Note, the different return value is actually an IE bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4365703/

Comment: @LGSon okay Thanks!, Thats what I thought, because label is not tabbable by default.